Homology and Cobordism maps
[I'm no expert in (co)bordism theory, and I've been struggling with it for the past few days. Any good references on this direction would be very helpful as well.]
Suppose $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a (continuous or appropriate) map of spaces. We know that it induces a map $f_*$ on homology.
It also induces a map $F$ on the (oriented) (co)bordism group $\Omega_n^{SO}(X) \rightarrow \Omega_n^{SO}(Y)$.
If $f$ induces a zero map on homology (in degrees $\geq 1$), what can we say about the (oriented) (co)bordism map $F$? Is it zero as well (in degrees $\geq 1$) ?
In particular, if $X$ and $Y$ are classifying spaces of infinite (discrete) groups (classifying space by the nerve construction), can we say that the (oriented) bordism map is zero as well?
That is, for two infinite discrete groups $G$ and $H$, suppose $f : G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism and induce zero map on homology groups (of the classifying spaces).
Then, is the induced map $\Omega_n^{SO}(BG) \rightarrow \Omega_n^{SO}(BH)$ zero (in degrees $\geq 1$)?

What if $G = H = {e}$?

:) Actually, what I have in mind, are infinite groups $G$ and $H$. I will edit the question.
